# Content-Security-Policy Spring Security via XML

Tags: spring-security

I am trying to add Content-Security-Policy using spring security using following spring-security-config.xml

```
<beans:beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

<security:http auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url
        pattern="/ResetPassword**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <headers defaults-disabled="true">
        <content-type-options />
        <hsts include-subdomains="true" max-age-seconds="31536000" />
        <content-security-policy
            policy-directives="script-src 'self' 
https://trustedscripts.example.com; object-src 
https://trustedplugins.example.com; report-uri /csp-report-endpoint/"
            report-only="true" />
    </headers>
</security:http>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="abc" authorities="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

I am getting the following error:
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 19; columnNumber: 26; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'content-security-policy'. One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":cache-control, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":xss-protection, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":hsts, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":frame-options, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":content-type-options, "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":header}' is expected.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)

Comment: did u get a fix for this pls